# How to define the name during stateful session bean context lookup?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, ejb, stateful

I'm setting up a stateful session bean and want to call it with context.lookup(name) but have no idea how to correctly define the name variable.

I'm working with Intellij and as far as I know there is no way to automatically generate this path as compared to NetBeans. I have tried multiple ways using the guideline I found for this name: 
java:scope[/app-name]/module-name/bean-name[!fully-qualified-interface-name]
However, I always get following error
 javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'RememberEJB' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: RememberEJB not found]

Below is the method which calls the function:

```
public Response getRememberedPost() {
    try {
        javax.naming.Context context = new InitialContext(); // Could also be InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
        RememberBean rememberBean = (RememberBean) context.lookup("RememberEJB");
        return Response.ok(rememberBean).build();
    }
    catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

I expect the name variable has to be something like "java:global/project-name/folder-for-beans/RememberEJB!src.Beans.RememberLocal" but this still gives the same error.

Comment: Hows your EJB bundled ? in the same WAR? or in a Different EAR file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the answer given by Ahmed Raaj but that still didn't work properly. I eventually found the right name by looking at the server log at startup which showed the JNDI name of my stateful bean. In my case this is the name shown below.

```
 RememberBean rememberBean = (RememberBean) context.lookup("java:global/DistributedGlassfish_ear_exploded/ejb/RememberEJB!Beans.RememberBean");
```

This was very close to what I tried before, I only didn't expect the '_ear_exploded' also had to be included.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below from [Java EE tutorial](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/ejb-intro004.html#GIRFL):

**Accessing Local Enterprise Beans Using the No-Interface View**
Client access to an enterprise bean that exposes a local, no-interface view is accomplished through either dependency injection or JNDI lookup.

- To obtain a reference to the no-interface view of an enterprise bean
  through dependency injection, use the `javax.ejb.EJB` annotation and
  specify the enterprise bean’s implementation class:

  ```
  @EJB    
  ExampleBean exampleBean;
  ```
- To obtain a reference to the no-interface view of an enterprise bean
  through JNDI lookup, use the javax.naming.InitialContext interface’s
  lookup method:

  ```
  ExampleBean exampleBean = (ExampleBean)InitialContext.lookup("java:module/ExampleBean");
  ```

So in your case:

```
    RememberBean rememberBean = (RememberBean)context.lookup("java:module/RememberEJB");
```